# how to use route slug inside resource routes

Tags: php, laravel

this is the usual way to define a slugged route in laravel

```
Route::get("/category/{category:id}/post/{post:id}","CategoryPostController@show");
```

notice that this route is actually binding the relation between the post and the category , which is belongsTo ,
thus , when you request `/category/1/post/1` and the post with id = 1 is actually belongs to category with id = 1 , the post will be returned

but if you request `/category/1/post/2` taking in hand that post with id =2 is not one of the posts that belong to category with id =1 , the result will be 404 Not Found

now , making use of resource routes , I actually became unable to do such a thing

for example ,

```
Route:apiResource("category.post","CategoryPostController");
```

this method is mapping the routes to deal with both resources of category and post , one of them is the route above `/category/{category}/post/{post}`

but without the slug .. , so how can I implement that inside the method without hardcoding the whole routes from scratch , thus , taking the benefit of resource routes .

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using?  and what "slug", you are only using 'id's here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `scoped` method on the `PendingResourceRegistration` object that gets returned from `Route::resource` (`apiResource` is calling `resource`):

```
Route:apiResource('category.post', 'CategoryPostController')->scoped();
```

If you need to override the route key that is used you can do that as well:

```
...->scoped(['post' => 'slug']);
```

If you wanted to use `apiResources` or `resources` which do not return anything you can pass an "options" array to them to set this information:

```
Route::apiResources([...], ['bindingFields' => []]);
// should be like adding `scoped` to each of them
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers - Scoping Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-scoping-resource-routes) `scoped`

Comment: I am using laravel 7.0 , does this exist there ?

Comment: thank you , one more question , if I used the resources() method which takes an array of controllers and prefixes , how this can be applied ?

Comment: unfortunately those methods `resources` and `apiResources` do not return anything, so you can not ... they just loop through what you pass to them and call the appropriate method anyway, you could do this yourself with a foreach loop if needed ... but there is an `options` array that you can pass to all these methods that you can potentially set this ... i will add to the answer